# How to connect to MariaDB using php over ssh

Tags: php, database, ssh

Now I am trying to connect MariaDB using php code over SSH.

My situation is like below,

1. I've uploaded my DB on my server:

   let server (ID : serverID, PW : serverPW)

   let mariaDB (ID : mariaID, PW : mariaPW)
2. I've written php code:

   $connect = mysql_connect(serverAddr, mariaID, mariaPW)
       die("mariadb connection error.");

above are not working. (print "mariadb connection error.")

I think it is because above don't have any information about server ID/PW.

How can I give serverID/serverPW info before code 2. ?

Comment: Please post the actual PHP code and format it accordingly. Also, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and you shouldn't use them. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should start using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) because in PHP 5.5 the `mysql_command` is deprecated so a good way to connect to the database is:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
try{
    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', 'username', 'password');
    $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

$query = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM table");
?>
```

Hope it helps!!!